# How to read into dataframe from feather bytes object

Tags: python, pandas, deserialization, feather

I have bytes object (it's feather data) in pandas dataframe as :

df[0]:

0    b'FEA1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...
Name: 0, dtype: object

How to deserialization object from df[0] (feather data) into dataframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the bytes object in an `pyarrow.BufferReader` and then read the file using the actual Feather implementation in `pyarrow`. Note the `feather` package is mainly an alias nowadays for the `pyarrow.feather` module.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.feather as feather

bytez = b'FEA1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00…'
reader = pa.BufferReader(bytez)
df = feather.read_feather(reader)
```

Comment: For getting bytes from dataframe `df[0].array.astype('bytes')[0]`